# Two saved figures, want them to show in a single graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure

Let's say I have two figures stored in separate files `A.fig` and `B.fig` which contain two separate plots. Is there a way to load `A.fig` and then do something like `hold on` and then load `B.fig` in the figure created for `A.fig` so that I have both plots in the same axes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export data from the graph in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216175/how-to-export-data-from-the-graph-in-matlab)

Comment: See also: [FIG files format](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format) on Undocumented MATLAB for a method that doesn't require opening the figure(s).

Comment: Someone had answered my question very thoroughly, where did it go?!

Comment: Can you show us an image of the figure so we can see if there are legends etc which will affect the answer

Comment: @secluded I deleted my answer because the linked duplicate contains the same information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I think the question is not really a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216175/how-to-export-data-from-the-graph-in-matlab) one. The OP does not ask for a way to extract the data but for a way to combine the two stored figures. Admittedly, he could extract the data and plot it again. But there is a more elegant solution...*

---

The actual plots are children of `axes` which is a child of `figure`. Therefore you can achieve what you want by copying the children of the second `axes` into the first `axes` with `copyobj`. Before that, load the figures with `openfig`. This method has the advantage to copy different types of 'plots' (`line`, `area`, ...).

The code to copy from `B.fig` to `A.fig` is as follows and works **starting from R2014b**:

```
fig1 = openfig('A');
fig2 = openfig('B', 'invisible');
copyobj(fig2.Children.Children, fig1.Children);
```

If you have a Matlab version **prior to R2014b**, you need to use the `set` and `get` functions since you cannot use `.`-notation. More information can be found [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html). You can either use `gca` to get the current axes after loading the figure like this:

```
fig1 = openfig('A');
ax1 = gca;
fig2 = openfig('B', 'invisible');
ax2 = gca;
copyobj(get(ax2,'children'), ax1);
```

... or `get` them manually from the `figure`-handle like this:

```
fig1 = openfig('A');
fig2 = openfig('B', 'invisible');
copyobj(get(get(fig2,'children'),'children'), get(fig1,'children'));
```

---

The following script creates two figures and then applies the above code to combine them. 
<sub>If you are have Matlab version R2013b or higher, replace `hgsave` with `savefig` as suggested in the [documentation](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html).</sub>

```
%% create two figure files
x = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
figure; hold on;
plot(x,sin(x),'b');
area(x,0.5*sin(x));
set(gca,'xlim',[0,2*pi]);
hgsave('A');
figure; hold on;
plot(x,cos(x),'r');
area(x,0.5*cos(x),'FaceColor','r');
hgsave('B');

%% clear and close all
clear;
close all;

%% copy process
fig1 = openfig('A');
fig2 = openfig('B', 'invisible');
copyobj(get(get(fig2,'children'),'children'), get(fig1,'children'));
close(fig2);
```

This gives the following result if manually combined in subplots:

[image: example]

Comment: You should note that your solution requires R2014b or newer for addressing graphics object properties with dot notation and R2013b or newer for `savefig`

Comment: @excaza Thanks for the suggestion. I added the get-equivalent as a solution for versions <R2014 and replaced `savefig` in the demo script.