# Exporting a figure into a csv after editing it

Tags: matlab

Is there any way that one could convert a figure into a csv or exportable matrix format from the plot window itself.

Like let's say you wanted to delete some points from a plot and then wanted to create a csv from it to put back into your code for later use.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to create a csv file from a figure. It is a terrible idea. either save the figure as an imaage or save the data as csv, but not the figure as csv

Comment: Because the figure has artifacts that I need to get rid of to perform another operation more smoothly.                                                                                        I'm essentially asking if there's a way to work backwards from the plot function. If you don't have an answer for me why bother responding?

Comment: There is nothing in that argument that suggests the need of a csv file.

Comment: I had trouble finding a way to imprint the changes I make on to the plot in the actual matrix values I have. I want to create a method that would allow me to run code again with an edited csv file.

Comment: Your wording is quite poor, the question is quite unclear. please, read [ask] and especially [mcve]

Comment: I really don't understand what's hard to understand here, I can reword it again. I have data of a coast line with about a thousand or so lat and long points. I plotted these points and I noticed a few extra points, I can delete the points from the plot but I need the data that comes from this shoreline to calculate other values.so I want to make a separate CSV to run again without these points included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do what you're asking; ultimately you need to mess around with object handles to extract the data from the plot.

If you don't need to do it from the plot window itself, then this answer ([How to export data from the graph in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216175/how-to-export-data-from-the-graph-in-matlab)) describes how to extract the `XData` and `YData` (assuming your plot is a line plot); you can then save it using [`csvwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html):

```
% Assuming that the data is a line or scatterplot
line_obj_handles = findobj(gca,'type','line');
% This will get the first line, modify this if you need a different one
handle = line_obj_handles(1);
% Extract the data
x = get(handle, 'XData');  % In R2014b or newer, x = handle.XData; also works
y = get(handle, 'YData');
csvwrite('data.csv', [x(:), y(:)]);
```

If you have more than one plot you will need to do a for loop over `line_obj_handles`.

If you really want to do it from the plot window, you can save the figure as a `.fig` file. This will contain all of the data in the figure; you can later load the figure and perform the same process to extract the X/Y data and write it to a CSV. A potential advantage of this approach, if you have many plots generated in the same way, is that you could write a script to automate this process.